# Mounting nfs causes infinite recursive directories on one of two RaspberryPi-s

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi-os-buster, nfs, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have a disk image file looped to the directories (with two partitions):

```
/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p1 
/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p2
```

These directories are normal `boot` and `root` partitions of `bookworm` image. I can `cd` to them and I see files there.

Then I am exporting these directories for `nfs` with `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p1 *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p2 *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

And now trying to mount it to `ttt` directory

```
cd ~
sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.68:/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p2 ttt
```

One one machine I see normal linux directory:

```
$ tree ttt
ttt
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
│   ├── cmdline.txt -> firmware/cmdline.txt
│   ├── ...
│   └── vmlinuz-6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8
├── dev
│   ├── console
│   ├── fd -> /proc/self/fd
│   └── ...
```

But on another machine I have infinite directory recursion:

```
$ tree ttt
ttt
└── srv
    └── bookworm-image
        ├── loop0p1
        │   ├── bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
        │   ├── ... (boot partition files)
        │   ├── kernel8.img
        │   ├── LICENCE.broadcom
        │   ├── overlays
        │   │   ├── act-led.dtbo
        │   │   ├── ...
        │   │   └── wm8960-soundcard.dtbo
        │   ├── start4cd.elf
        │   ├── ...
        │   └── System Volume Information
        │       └── WPSettings.dat
        └── loop0p2
            └── srv
                └── bookworm-image
                    ├── loop0p1
                    │   ├── bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
                    │   ├── ... (boot partition files)
                    │   ├── bcm2711-rpi-cm4s.dtb
...   
                    └── loop0p2
                        └── srv
                            └── bookworm-image
                                ├── loop0p1
                                │   ├── ...
```

Looks like it has error with starting mount location having each time it tries to see the root of the mounted image but showing the root of the host system instead.

Why it can be?

Machines have different versions. "Good" machine is `buster`:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
...
Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 000000002a90019f
Model           : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

And "bad" machine is `bookworm`:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
...
Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 00000000c837ea85
Model           : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
 $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

`nfs` versions are the same.

What can be a reason?

---

I found, that on "bad" machine I can't mount with version 3

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o vers=3 127.0.0.1:/srv/bookworm-image/loop0p2 ttt

mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Nov 24 00:48:57 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,addr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 59834
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,addr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 59834
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,addr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 59834
mount.nfs: mount(2): Stale file handle
mount.nfs: Stale file handle
```

Comment: Help me out, please... a loop mount is for mounting a file, so how does `nfs` come to be involved in this? Why not just mount the loop from the machine you'll be working from? Beyond that, not sure `nfs` can handle a loop device... maybe `samba` can?

Comment: I need to access the share from another device. This is why I am using `nfs`. Local mount is for testing purposes. `nfs` can handle loop devices, because (1) it handles another partition and (2) it hadles both partitions on another host.